# Prove that: $(AV)^⊥ = (A^T)^{−1}(V^⊥).$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in R^{n×n}$ and V be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I have to prove that:

$(AV)^⊥ = (A^T)^{−1}(V^⊥).$

From the lectures I know that we have that the orthogonal complement is gyven by:

$V^⊥$ = ${y \in \mathbb{R}^n | y^Tx = 0 \space \forall x \in V}$ and that we have $(V^⊥)^⊥ = V$.

Any help would be fine. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in (AV)^\perp$, it means $x^TAv=0$ for all $v\in V$, that is,
$$(A^Tx)^Tv=0\ \text{ for all }v\in V$$
so that $A^Tx\in V^\perp$, hence $x\in (A^T)^{-1}(V^\perp)$.

The converse follows similarly.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Do I have to prove the converse? Or isn't that necessary?